# Export model with rigifi to fbx

Tags: rigify

could you please tell me how to export model with rigifi When I export to fbx it comes as normal rig

When I am trying to import my model it shows normal rig it is very tough to animation please tell me how to export model with rigifi to export please

Comment: If by "normal rig" you mean bones without constraints and custom shapes, that's expected. There is no standard definition for these, so they are mostly unsupported by exchange formats and softwares' import tools.